# Problem with login

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, facebook

I'm trying to login with my email and password, but stackexchange.com automatically recognise that I once made a log in with fb and every time tries to log in from there without allowing me to enter email and password. I can only access to my browser while on private mode.

The problems seem to be that it linked a new account to my fb login. This is caused by the cookies.

But I cannot unlink my fb account to my account. Do you know how to solve that?

What happens:
1. go to stack exchange.com
2. Try to login with my account. If the cookies are deleted it works. If not it goes back to the homepage.
3. When I'm in my actual account and try to link my fb page to the account there is an error within stackexchange.

Comment: If you read the Related sidebar to the right, do any of them solve your problem.

Comment: Did you try to clear those cookies?

Comment: There are no FB credentials on the account you used to post this. Can you elaborate on what steps you take to log in and what happens at each step? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I cleared the cookies, but I still cannot link my fb page to my actual account.

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to *add* Facebook as a login? And you're seeing an error? What does the error say?

Comment: The error is caused by stackexchange and that they will look at it, but without guaranteeing that they will resolve it

Comment: @Dave7 Can you gather up some screenshots for what you're seeing at each stage, please? And/or let me know when the last time was that you tried this (so I can dig through exception and traffic logs to see what's broken).